# Can I make Office 365 shared documents read-only? (OneDrive for Business)

Tags: file-sharing, onedrive

I have to share some Microsoft Office 365 documents (word, excel) with others. I want them to be strictly read-only..

I share them through the company OneDrive (which came with Office 365 subscription).

Can it be done?

EDIT : I need to use the same file for editing by myself in the same place (ie **avoiding** storing original copy somewhere else)

Comment: [Read sharing documents or folders in Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-documents-or-folders-in-Office-365-1fe37332-0f9a-4719-970e-d2578da4941c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert files to an image.

You can convert files to a PDF.

You can password protect the files.

[Add or remove protection in your document, workbook, or presentation](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Add-or-remove-protection-in-your-document-workbook-or-presentation-05084cc3-300d-4c1a-8416-38d3e37d6826)

Comment: first 2 are not an option. I will have to keep my local copy of the original file. the 3d option is what I wanted. thank you!

Comment: It looks like that this feature requires the recipients to have at least a Live ID. Is it possible to share folders with "View" rights with anyone who has the folder url (like in Dopbox etc)?